# linq-to-sql is this the most efficient code review

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

hey all. Just wanting to know is this the most efficient way of getting values from a db: given;

```
-----------    ---------------    -------------
| Channel |    |Issue        |    |Topic      |
| path(ck)|    |channelID(fk)|    |issueID(fk)|
-----------    ---------------    -------------
```

- One channel has many Issues
- One Issue has many Topics
- path is an alternate key

I have written the following linq statment.

```
var content = (from c in db.Channels
where c.channel_holding_page == path
select new { c, _latestIssue = c.Issues.OrderBy(i => i.issue_created).Where(i => i.issue_isVisible == true).FirstOrDefault(), _topics = c.Issues.OrderBy(i => i.issue_created).Where(i => i.issue_isVisible == true).FirstOrDefault().Topics }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to get(working backwards here) all the topics associated with the latest issue(issue_created) that is set to be public(issue_isVisible) from said channel.

Is this the most efficient way or is there a method that would be quicker then this.

Comment: There is one sub-query that is repeated twice. Perhaps it would be a little easier to understand if that were broken out into a separate statement. That will still not result in an extra trip to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes querying down works well, and you can drill up, as in:

```
from t in Topic
join i in issues
on t.IssueID equals i.IssueID
join c in channels
on i.ChannelID equals c.ChannelID
where c.Chanel_holding_path == path
select new
{
   i.issue_visible,
   c.channelid,
   t.topicID
}
```

Not exact,but you get the picture.  You can drill up which makes it easier to work with objects.

Comment: The code is much cleaner the way you have put it. I agree it is not exactly getting the same result as my example above but all i was after was a methodology thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your code is trying to accomplish:

```
     var channels = db.channels.Where (c => c.channel_holding_page == path);
     var issues = channels.Select (c => new { c, _latestIssue = c.Issues.Where (i => i.issue_isVisible).OrderBy (i => i.issue_created).FirstOrDefault () });
     var result = issues.Select (ci => new { ci.c, ci._latestIssue, ci._latestIssue.Topics }).FirstOrDefault ();
```

If there will be only one channel that will match the channel_holding_page check, then we can simplify this a bit more since the channels var can be flattened using a FirstOrDefault() right in the first line.

Comment: would that then relate to 3 separate calls to the db?

Comment: No, just one. It's only when you actually try to pull objects out of the enumerators (like channels, issues, results) that the query is actually run.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when u change places of .Where and .OrderBy it will speed the query up a bit.

Comment: ffs who gave a minus? comments on that please